# Finding outliers further than certain standard deviations from mean for a data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, outliers

I understand that to find rows in a data frame that meet certain criteria (ie. filtering data) I would use a code similar to:

```
s[(s$age < 20 | s$age > 40)]
```

But would I go about trying to find the outlier rows that have 'age' values + or - 1 standard deviation from the mean?

```
s <- data.frame(
  sample = c("s_1", "s_2", "s_3", "s_4", "s_5", "s_6", "s_7", "s_8"),
  flavor = c("original", "chicken", "original", "original", "cheese", "chicken", "cheese", "original"),
age = c(23, 25, 11, 5, 6, 44, 50, 2),
  scale = c( 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 5))
```

Comment: Try `std(s$age) + 1` ... Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: You are missing a comma from your first code. However to apply a threshold (`mean(x) + 1sd(x)`) you will need to use `apply` family. Also why just 1 sd? It does not sound accurate

Comment: I simply chose 1 as a random number so I could better understand R. But yes, you're right this value is pretty small for outliers.

Comment: FYI my comment for using apply methods was refering to rowwise operations.

Comment: a bit simpler solution `s[abs(scale(s$age)) > 1,  ]`

Comment: std not found, @Val

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the outliers based on the initial statistics, it's straightforward:

`s[(s$age < mean(s$age) - sd(s$age) | s$age > mean(s$age) + sd(s$age),]`

This uses the base function `sd`. Also since you stated you want to select rows of a `data.frame`, I added a `,` to the indexing so it will return all columns.

If you want a continuous, filtering-like approach, you can use the `apply` - family functionality as mentioned by @Sotos

Comment: That is not what OP means. 1 sd away from the mean. See my comment on the question.